# Invariant Violation: Unable to find node on an unmounted component when using a timer with enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have a react-table with both click and doubleclick events on the rows, which required the use of a timer to make both events work.

The single click event selects a row in the state, so I had to use a timer in the unit test to properly check the state change. I then try to simulate a click on the row again, but get `Uncaught [Invariant Violation: Unable to find node on an unmounted component.]`

The test passed fine before I added the timer logic, so I can only assume that the component is somehow unmounted before my timer callback is called, even though I don't call done() until the callback.

Maybe this just isn't going to work?

My pacakge.json:

```
"react": "^16.8.6",
"enzyme": "^3.9.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.13.1",
"jest": "^22.4.4"
```

The code I'm trying to test:

```
let timer;
const delay = 200;
// extraneous stuff removed
return {
  onClick: e => {
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    if (!prevent && rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
        this.setSelectedRecord(rowInfo.original);
        this.props.onSelect && this.props.onSelect(rowInfo.original[primaryKey]);
    }
      prevent = false;
    }, delay);
  },
  onDoubleClick: e => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    prevent = true;
    if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
      this.setSelectedRecord(null);
      this.props.onDoubleClick && this.props.onDoubleClick(rowInfo.original[primaryKey]);
    }
  }
};
```

The failing unit test:

```
  it('selects row on single click', async (done) => {
        const mockCallback = jest.fn();
        const newProps = {...props, data: data, schema: schema, onSelect: mockCallback};
        const wrapper = mount(<QueryRecordsTable {...newProps} />);
        const rows = wrapper.find(Tooltip);
        // 3 fields * 2 records
        expect(rows.length).toEqual(6);
        rows.at(0).simulate('click');
        setTimeout(() => {
            expect(mockCallback.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual(ID1);
            expect((wrapper.state() as any).selectedRecord.ID).toEqual(ID1);
            expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
            const rows2 = wrapper.find(Tooltip);
            rows2.at(3).simulate('click');
        }, 300);
    });
```

When the simulate from within the callback is called, I get this:

```
 Error: Uncaught [Invariant Violation: Unable to find node on an unmounted component.]
        at reportException (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)
        at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\Window.js:680:7)
        at ontimeout (timers.js:458:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:296:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:259:5) { Invariant Violation: Unable to find node on an unmounted component.
        at invariant (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:55:15)
        at findCurrentFiberUsingSlowPath (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:4166:7)
        at findCurrentHostFiber (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:4235:23)
        at findHostInstanceWithWarning (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:20629:21)
        at Object.findDOMNode (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:21138:14)
        at mapper (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16\build\ReactSixteenAdapter.js:304:61)
        at _nodeToHostNode (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16\build\ReactSixteenAdapter.js:313:10)
        at ReactSixteenAdapter.nodeToHostNode (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16\build\ReactSixteenAdapter.js:906:21)
        at Object.simulateEvent (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16\build\ReactSixteenAdapter.js:532:31)
        at ReactWrapper.<anonymous> (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\enzyme\build\ReactWrapper.js:953:29)
        at ReactWrapper.single (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\enzyme\build\ReactWrapper.js:1720:25)
        at ReactWrapper.simulate (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\enzyme\build\ReactWrapper.js:952:21)
        at setTimeout (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\src\components\SelectRecords\__tests__\QueryRecordsTable.test.tsx:67:25)
        at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (D:\mdm\mdm-ui\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\Window.js:678:19)
        at ontimeout (timers.js:458:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:296:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:259:5) name: 'Invariant Violation', framesToPop: 1 }
```